# Formula, Circle's perimeter intersects with corners of rectangle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, formula, mathematical-optimization

[image]

**Note: Everything about the circle is unknown. Only the width and height of the rectangle are known.**

I devised a formula to determine the diameter of circle, so that the circle's perimeter intersects with the bottom two corners of a rectangle, whatever the proportion of the rectangle is (or at least if the width is greater than the height). The formula is as follows, whereby W refers to the width and H refers to the height of the rectangle:

```
X = W / H
Diameter = ((X/4) + (1/X)) * W
```

**Does anybody know a more eloquent way to calculate this or is there a known algorithm to do this more efficiently?**

Comment: you can just force the circle to pass through 3 points (the bottom 2 and the top one in the middle) and from there you can derive the diameter: https://qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/circle%20given%203%20points.htm

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia cool, although i do not understand much of it because i am not trained in mathematics. if you had to write the formula like i wrote my own in my question, how would you write it?

Comment: How did you come up with that formula?

Comment: @AKSingh by analyzing the shapes and numbers and patterns therein. how come?

Comment: Does your formula work?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat does that first formula work if u dont know anything about the circle in the first place? what does `h` stand for in `h+w^2/(4h)`?

Comment: @AKSingh yes, it works, but im hoping somebody knows how to improve it

Comment: @DavidEisenstat ohhhhh right man it is 5 AM so i am not thinking straight sorry. `4h` means `4*h`, correct?

Comment: you can find an implementation here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equation-of-circle-when-three-points-on-the-circle-are-given/

Comment: but probably since you know how those 3 points are arranged, you can make some improvement to this formula

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia does that formula work, even if all of the details of the circle are unknown?

Comment: If your formula works, I suggest using it. It is way more simpler.

Comment: Also, doesn't the circle also touch the top part of the rectangle?

Comment: @oldboy that formula works for every combination of 3 points that you give it, not only for the arrangement you are working on

Comment: @AKSingh yes, the circle touches the top middle point of the rectangle and the two bottom corners of the rectangle touch the perimeter. the formula can be expressed as `W / H = X; ((X/4) + (1/X)) * W`, but hoping there is a simpler way. i have an idea in mind for simplifying it, which i will try now

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia ah, okay, cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Letting the center of the circle be (0, 0), the diameter be D, the width of the rectangle be W, and the height be H, the points (±W/2, D/2 − H) should lie on the circle, which by Pythagoras holds if and only if

> (W/2)<sup>2</sup> + (D/2 − H)<sup>2</sup> = (D/2)<sup>2</sup>.

Expanding the binomial and subtracting (D/2)<sup>2</sup> from both sides, we get

> W<sup>2</sup>/4 − D H + H<sup>2</sup> = 0.

Solving for D by adding D H to both sides and dividing through by H, we get

> D = W<sup>2</sup>/(4 H) + H.

In code this could be as follows.

```c
double diameter(double width, double height) {
  return width * width / (4 * height) + height;
}
```

Comment: let me just double check it in my graphics editor. this formula would be superior to mine since i would need 2 operations like in my edited question

Comment: it seems to check out. ty so much! glad we could combine everything into one single formula :D